# showing error "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Tags: java

In my code ..I want it to save a pdf file which contains detail of employee
but it's not saving pdf file and just showing

> "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Need help....I m not understanding..what is the problem with this code.
I think revoking result set and preparedstatement has some problem.

```
    private void txt_searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{

            String sql ="select * from staff_info where id=? ";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {

            int add1 =rs.getInt("id");
            txt_id.setText(add1+"");

            String add2 =rs.getString("first_name");
            txt_firstname.setText(add2);

            String add3 =rs.getString("surname");
            txt_surname.setText(add3);

            String add4 =rs.getString("Dob");
            txt_dob.setText(add4);

            String add5 =rs.getString("Department");
            txt_dep.setText(add5);

            String add7 =rs.getString("Salary");
            txt_salary.setText(add7);

            String add8 =rs.getString("Status");
            txt_status.setText(add8);

            String add9 =rs.getString("Date_hired");
            txt_doj.setText(add9);

            String add10 =rs.getString("job_title");
            txt_job.setText(add10);

            String add17 =rs.getString("Designation");
            txt_desig.setText(add17);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data");
        }
        finally {

            try{

               /* rs.close();
                pst.close();*/

            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }                                      

    private void txt_firstnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void txt_jobActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void txt_salaryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        // TODO add your handling code here:

                 String value = txt_firstname.getText();
            String value0 = txt_surname.getText();
            String value1 = txt_id.getText();
            String value2 = txt_desig.getText();
            String value3 = txt_desig.getText();


            JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
            dialog.setSelectedFile(new File(value +" "+ value0+"-Salary Slip"+".pdf"));
            int dialogResult = dialog.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (dialogResult==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            String filePath = dialog.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

          for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            String sql ="select * from deductions where emp_id = '"+value1+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery(); 
            String val = rs.getString(5);
            String reason = rs.getString(6);

           rs.close();
            pst.close();

            String sq ="select * from allowance where emp_id = '"+value1+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sq);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();


           int calcTotal = Integer.parseInt(txt_salary.getText());
           float x = Float.valueOf(rs.getString(9));
           int v = Integer.parseInt(val);
           float total = calcTotal+ x -v;

           Document myDocument = new Document();
           PdfWriter myWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(myDocument, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
           myDocument.open();

           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("PAY SLIP",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,20,Font.BOLD )));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
           myDocument.add((new Paragraph("EMPLOYEE DETAILS",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD))));
           myDocument.add((new Paragraph("Name of Employee: " +value + " "+value0,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN))));
           myDocument.add((new Paragraph("Designation: "+value2,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN))));
           myDocument.add((new Paragraph("Department: "+value3,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN))));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("SALARY",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Basic Salary: $"+calcTotal,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Overtime: "+rs.getString(2)+" Hours",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Medical: $" +rs.getString(3),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Bonus: $"+rs.getString(4),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Other: $"+rs.getString(5),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("DEDUCTION",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Deduction Details: "+reason,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Total Deductions : $"+val ,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("TOTAL PAYMENT",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Total Earnings: "+rs.getString(9),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("Net Pay : " +total,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN)));
           myDocument.add(new Paragraph("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));


           myDocument.newPage();
           myDocument.close();  
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Report was successfully generated");
          }

     }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);


     }
     finally {

            try{
               rs.close();
               pst.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

            }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is your result set null?

Comment: @schtever you're right there's another section where rs needs to advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea for handling the result set in an earlier section of your code, but fail to use it elsewhere.  In the section for `jButton1ActionPerformed`, you execute the query, but don't do `rs.next()` to actually move to the first item in the result set.  Be sure to do that before you try and manipulate the result set, otherwise you're going to keep getting that exception.

Comment: i have corrected my both mistakes but still showing "Before start of result set " Exception...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you're handling the 'id' column inconsistently; this could lead to weirdness in the JDBC driver.  In the preparedStatement, you're treating it as a string with

```
pst.setString(1, ...)
```

but in the resultset you're treating it as an int with

```
rs.getInt("id")
```